# How to check if a char and/or string is uppercase or lowercase

Tags: c#, linq, char, uppercase, lowercase

How can I check if a `char` is uppercase or lowercase in c# and also if every letter in a `string` is uppercase or lowercase?

Comment: I simple way is to convert to uppercase and then compare to original string.  If it matches then it is uppercase.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will work:

```
char hLow = 'h';         
char hHigh = 'H';        

char.IsLower(hLow);      //returns true
char.IsUpper(hHigh);     //returns true
```

This would work as well (but it's a rather old-school approach to it and doesn't work for accent letters):

```
(hLow >= 'a' && hLow <= 'z');      //returns true
(hHigh >= 'A' && hHigh <= 'Z');     //returns true
```

Also, if you want to check if all characters in a `string` are uppercase/lowercase, you can do it like this:

```
string word = "UPPERCASE";

word.All(char.IsUpper);     //returns true
word.All(char.IsLower);     //returns false
```

Keep in mind that you need to have `using System.Linq;` in the beginning of your code for this to work.

And if you want to check if a `string` only contains letters, just use this (still using `Linq`):

```
word.All(char.IsLetter);    //returns true
```

There are more useful functions like this in `Linq` which you can find yourself.

Comment: " if every letter in a string is uppercase or lowercase?" you probably meant to use `All` and not `Any`

Comment: To check if all characters are uppercase it should be `word.All(char.IsUpper)`

Comment: "(hLow >= 'a' && h <= 'z');" is the `h` meant to be `hLow` ?

Comment: the `(hLow >= 'a' && hLow <= 'z'); ` check would fail for `'á'` (note the accent), `Char.IsLower('á')` works